# input field should hide when select value is 'others'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

im trying to hide the input field (id: mopothers) when select (id: mop) value is not 'Others' but the input field doesn't hide

script-----------

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('select[name=mop]').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '5') {
            $('#mopothers').show();
        } else {
            $('#mopothers').hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

html-------

```
<div data-row-span="2">
            <div data-field-span="1">
                <label>
                    Mode of Payment
                </label>
                <select id = "mop" name = "mop">
                    <option value="">Select mode of payment</option>
                    <option value="1">Cash</option>
                    <option value="2">Check</option>
                    <option value="3">Card</option>
                    <option value="4" >Bank Transfer</option>
                    <option value="5">Others</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div data-field-span="1">

                    <label>
                        <?php
                            if(isset($_SESSION['mopothersrequired'])) {
                                echo '<label style="color: red; ">
                                        *Mode of Payment (Others) is Required
                                         </label>';
                                unset($_SESSION['mopothersrequired']);  
                            }
                            else echo '<label>
                                        Mode of Payment (Others)
                                         </label>';  
                        ?>
                    </label>

                <input type="text" id = "mopothers" name = "mopothers">
            </div>
        </div>
```

an input field should appear once the user chooses others and hide once he chooses cash, check, card, bank or check

Comment: Did you add the script after the elements in the DOM, you don't have a DOM ready handler.

Answer (score 1):

Try to invoke the `change` event in the initial stage once,

```
$('select[name=mop]').change(function () {
   $('#mopothers').toggle($(this).val() === '5');
}).change();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/43ujzkc5/1/)